# Mockito fails to run stubbed methods

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I'm trying to stub a method of a class (spring-data-jpa repository) by returning a User object whenever the string "john" is passed in.

What happens is, within the userService when users.findByUsername("john") is called it always returns null and not any User object as I have defined by:

```
when(users.findByUsername("john"))
    .thenReturn(any(User.class));
```

When I place  breakpoint in the test method and compare users with userService.users they are equal.

I have no clue on why this is happening maybe because UserRepository is just an interface ?

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ServiceTestContext.class)
public class UserServiceImplTests {

@InjectMocks
private UserServiceImpl userService;

@Mock
private UserRepository users;

@Test
public void signupUser_alreadyExistingUsername_userCreatedWithRandomGeneratedUsername() {
    // .. creation of emailSignupCommand Object

    when(users.findByUsername("john"))
            .thenReturn(any(User.class));
    userService.signupUser(emailSignupCommand);

    User expectedUser = new User.Builder()
            .withEmail(EMAIL)
            .withPassword(PASSWORD)
            .build();

    // ... verification code
}
```

}

pom version

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

[image: idea debugger variables view]

Comment: I think you need to share more of your code. What does "... verification code" look like? Where is the line that behaves differently from your expectations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method can't return "any" User instance. You have to tell it to return a given User.

`any()`can be used as a stubbed method argument, to say for example: whatever the ID you're called with, I want you to return John:

```
when(users.findByUsername(any(String.class)))
        .thenReturn(new User("John");
```

Comment: thank you for clearing that out for me but, chaning the return value from any to an actual object has no effects on the problem I'm having.

Comment: Then your stub is probably not called with "john" as argument.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is called with "john" as argument. Debugging through it and looking at the variables showed me some nastly looking exception message. See screenshot I've added in the original post.

Comment: Well, it seems you keep using a matcher in "thenReturn()" although, as my answer explains, this is invalid.